# How to convert hits from Top 10 plugin to WordPress Popular Posts?

Tags: plugins

How can I import/convert hits from the plugin top 10 to wordpress popular posts plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

You don't.

## Long Answer

These two plugins are fundamentally different.  Popular Posts stores views in a custom field with each post.  Top 10 creates a new table in the database and stores views there.

So you'll need to look for the `wp_top-ten` table in your database.  It should have these fields:

- `postnumber`
- `cntaccess`

`postnumber` is the ID of your post and `cntaccess` is the number of views it has.  You can move this into the `pvc_views` custom field for the post to migrate the data.

You'll likely need to script this in SQL; that's an exercise I leave to you.  In reality, you'd be better served just switching to the new plugin and starting your counter from scratch.

Comment: ok, thnx a lot :)